# How to show wordpress parent catgorie page show subcategories list

Tags: wordpress, categories

It's possible parent categories show subcategories list (name,image,description)

Example

Parent Category:

- Subcategory name 1.1(Title)
  Subcategory image
  Subcategory description
- Subcategory name 1.2(Title)
  Subcategory image
  Subcategory description

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this. Please find the code given below,

```
<?php $this_category = get_category($cat); ?>   

<ul class="product_list">
    <?php
    $id = get_query_var('cat');
    $args = array(  'parent' => $id );
    foreach (get_categories($args) as $cat) : ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
        <p><?php echo $cat->description; ?></p>

    </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks,
Vino

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
<?php wp_list_categories('child_of=parent_cat_id'); ?>
```

Referance [This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: This code showing for subcategories title only. Now how to show subcategories Description and subcategories image.

Comment: how can you  set image for category?

Comment: <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>

Comment: I'm using categories images plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/